# What is a single word for when "milk boils and flows out"?

Tags: nouns, image-identification

When we boil milk and after a few minutes it flows out of the pan, 
what is the single word to describe this action or appearance?

[image]

Comment: tumbler is not correct word. i think. pls replace with some word.

Comment: I think the fault lies in the language skills of the questioner. I think we should be a little forgiving rather than being trigger-happy on the close button/link. Sometimes, if a person knows how to "properly" asks a question, he probably would already know the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'd call this [boiling over](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/boil-over):

> (of a ​liquid) to ​rise up in a ​cooking ​container and ​flow over the ​edge
>
> If a ​liquid that is being ​heated ​boils over, it ​rises up and ​flows over the ​edge of the ​pan:
>
> *Take the ​milk off the ​heat before it ​boils over.*

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a horror movie. A bunch of bugs enters a person's ears and then the person falls to the ground dying, and the mouth frothing with bubbles.

Imagine another movie - a teenage comedy. The student mixes two liquids into a large beaker, and it starts to froth over. And then mayhem ensues.

Imagine Harry Potter movie, or better still, Once Upon a Time TV series. The green witch Zelena (Rebecca Mader), throws in a bunch of stuffs into her cauldron and stirs the concoction. Then it bubbles and froths over.

Usually when you boil milk, rice or oat, they tend to froth - form bubbles which overflows.

#### [froth (frɒθ)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/froth)

n

1. a mass of small bubbles of air or a gas in a liquid, produced by fermentation, detergent, etc
2. (Pathology) a mixture of saliva and air bubbles formed at the lips in certain diseases, such as rabies
3. trivial ideas, talk, or entertainment

vb

4. to produce or cause to produce froth
5. (tr) to give out in the form of froth
6. (tr) to cover with froth

[from Old Norse frotha or frauth; related to Old English āfrēothan to foam, Sanskrit prothati he snorts]

- frothy adj
- frothily adv
- frothiness n

*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014*

Comment: I would avoid *froth* in this particular case, as **frothed milk** is a common term for milk that's used in cappuccinos and other coffee drinks.

Comment: Just for a phenomenon of the last 15 years, I have to change my language?

Comment: You don't *have* to, it all depends on how much you want to confuse millennials.